# Has the previous student council president really appeared in the anime?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

According to the [fandom](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Previous_Student_Council_President), while the guy's manga debut is [Chapter 121](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_121), the guy's anime debut episode is actually [episode 17](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_17), which adapts [Chapter 36](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_36), [Chapter 63](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_63), [Chapter 64](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_64) and [Chapter 66](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_66)...meaning the anime did something different from the manga...

Was the guy really there? Which part?

Comment: The wiki for the character mentions "*(Cameo)*" and the "Trivia" section on episode 17 shows that he's at the bottom-right corner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH WOW THANKS Aki Tanaka ♦. Ok it's like this:

1 - It says in trivia for episode 17

> The shot of Chika leading the student body in singing the school anthem features a large number of recognizable characters in it, all of whom are properly ordered according to their grade and class.

In the episode you don't see their faces. You're supposed to recognise them from their accessories or something.

[image]

But it's the guy on the bottom right:

[image]

In the fandom there's an image that identifies them

[image]

And yeah on the bottom right:

[image]